# React Native issues passing functions

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to React Native, and what i am trying to do is, that i would like to pass getUPCfromApi(upc) to ScanditSDK.js component, inside the onScan function. But i get this error see attached img.
[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM6yF.jpg)

### Api.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ScanditSDK from './components/ScanditSDK'

export default class Api extends Component{
  getUPCfromApi = (upc) => {
   try {
    let response = fetch(
      `https://api.upcdatabase.org/product/${upc}/API_KEY`);
    let responseJson = response.json();
    return responseJson;
    console.log('response',responseJson);
  }  catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
 }
  render(){
   return(
   <ScanditSDK 
   getUPCfromApi={this.getUPCfromApi}
   />
   ) 
  }
}
```

ScanditSDK.js contains scanner module. Inside the onScan method i am calling getUpcFromApi(upc) which i made inside Api.js

### ScanditSDK.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  findNodeHandle,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import {
  BarcodePicker,
  ScanditModule,
  ScanSession,
  Barcode,
  SymbologySettings,
  ScanSettings
} from 'react-native-scandit';

ScanditModule.setAppKey('APIKEY');



export class ScanditSDK extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      upc: '',
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.scanner.startScanning();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'column'}}>
            <BarcodePicker
                onScan={(session) => { this.onScan(session) }}
                scanSettings= { this.settings }
        ref={(scan) => { this.scanner = scan }}
                style={{ flex: 1 }}/>
    </View>
    );
  }

  onScan = (session) => {
    this.setState({upc:session.newlyRecognizedCodes[0].data })
    alert(session.newlyRecognizedCodes[0].data + " " + session.newlyRecognizedCodes[0].symbology);
    this.props.getUPCfromApi(this.state.upc)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `props` to access your function. change your onScan function as below

```
onScan = (session) => {
    this.setState({upc:session.newlyRecognizedCodes[0].data })
    alert(session.newlyRecognizedCodes[0].data + " " + session.newlyRecognizedCodes[0].symbology);
    this.props.getUPCfromApi(this.state.upc)
  }
```

And in your `Api` component. Bind your function in constructor.

```
constructor(props){
super(props)
this.getUPCfromApi = this.getUPCfromApi.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i apoligize i did not post the right code from my editor, i did already have this.props.getUPCfromApi(this.state.upc) and i get the error above (see image)

Comment: Check my edit. you need to bind the function as well.

Comment: I added the binding inside constructor, but still the same error.

Comment: Okay. let me see you Api component .can you post this? or update the original post

Comment: I added ScanditSDK.js and Api.js to codeshare. https://codeshare.io/21pD03

Comment: can you log `this.props` in `componentDidMount` in ScanditSDK.js? and let me know what's there

Comment: I added this.props.getUPCfromApi..... to compomentDidMount, it returns same error see image: https://imgur.com/a/oxShw

Comment: No am just telling you to log `this.props` in didMount and show me the output